# Python Threading Lock Print Empty Line

Tags: python, eclipse, multithreading

I am learning [Python Threading Module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) right now. And since the output of each thread will point to the same target, either database or write to flatfile, I would assume using Lock.acquire and Lock.release before and after the output process of each Thread.

```
from threading import Thread, Lock
import time

def task(argument1, lock):
    lock.acquire()
    print 'processing ' + str(argument1)
    lock.release()

    time.sleep(5)
    # Your baby code goes here

    lock.acquire()
    print 'finish processing' + str(argument1)
    lock.release()


class Worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, argument1, lock):
        Thread.__init__(self)       
        self.value = argument1     
        self.lock = lock

    def run(self):
        task(self.value, self.lock)            # calling the routine 


def main():
    l = Lock()

    worker1 = Worker('BAV99', l)
    worker2 = Worker('ATMEGA328', l)
    worker3 = Worker('LM340', l)

    worker1.start()
    worker2.start()
    worker3.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
```

You might got confused by the usage of Lock. In a short sentence, without the lock, you might get the print spread out.

WITHOUT LOCK:

```
processing BAV99
processing ATMEGA328
processing LM340
finish processingBAV99finish processingLM340finish processingATMEGA328
```

WITH LOCK:

```
processing BAV99 
processing ATMEGA328
processing LM340
finish processingBAV99
finish processingLM340
finish processingATMEGA328
```

The problem is:
***I have  spotted that sometimes there exist empty line between the outputs like below and wondering what is really going on there, or it is just some illusion caused by eclipse.***

```
processing BAV99 
processing ATMEGA328
processing LM340

finish processingBAV99
finish processingLM340
finish processingATMEGA328
```

SORRY THAT THE ERROR COULD NOT BE REPEATED and that is what haunted me the most.